# How do I update a query according to Email of the user?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a username field in my profile page. First of all, to access that profile page, the user must log in. And is identified through a unique value in this case, his email. Now back to the username field. Currently, my username query inserts whatever username I enter, to the id 1 of the MySQL database. I want it to update according to the email of the user. This way it'll be inserted to the correct row.

It's current working is as following:

As you can see, I'm inputting the username from a different e-mail:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiXkE.jpg

But it still updates in the ID 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N0WW.jpg

This is my **action.php**:

```
<?php
session_start(); //---> start session
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id1753243_venom', 'roushan123', 'id1753243_gameware_01');
if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not connected to the server';
}
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username)."' WHERE id = 1";
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //---> this will store username into session variable
}

if(!$insert)
{
    echo 'Not inserted';
}
else
{
    echo 'Inserted';
}
header("refresh:2; url=user.php");
?>
```

I'm a beginner but I do know the problem is in the `WHERE` clause. What I don't know is, **how to change the code to my needs i.e update the query and store username according to the email of the user logged in..** I'm hoping one of you can help me in this case! Thanks a lot!

**PS: I know the PHP code is not secure, this is just a test.**

Comment: assuming you have e-mail parameter in your post and e-mail column in your DB, you should go with something like this:
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username)."' WHERE e-mail='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['e-mail'])."'";

Comment: I get the following error on executing the page:

**Notice: Undefined variable: insert in /storage/ssd1/243/1753243/public_html/login-system/action.php on line 18
Not inserted**

Comment: Changed $_POST['email'] to $_SESSION['email'] and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Query is correct but you have made a little mistake of email parameter in query. There should be a email parameter in posted data and email column in table then  change the query by altering the where condition as mentioned below:
WHERE id = 1 to email=$_POST['e-mail']

Comment: Your answer contains SQL injection.